# Jquery: how to highlight checked radio bution block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have the following code, I want to add/remove the class to `<span class " ui-message ui-state-highlight">` to the radio button checked to highlight the checked line.
How do i go about do that?

Here is my html  and JS below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#loan_origination_application input').on('change', function() {
           $('input[name=address]:checked', '#loan_origination_application').addClass("ui-message ui-state-highlight"); 
           alert($('input[name=address]:checked', '#loan_origination_application').val()); 
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group radio_buttons optional address-b">
    <label class="radio_buttons optional control-label">Your addresses</label>
        <span class="radio ui-message ui-state-highlight">
        <br />
    <label for="user_address1 ">
    <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="user_address1" name="address" type="radio" value="addres1" checked><strong>Sally Smith</strong> 3  Plaza, Luiville, Az 932973, United States <a href="#">Edit</a>
    <br />
    </label>
                    </span>
                    <span class="radio">
                        <label for="user_address2">
                            <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="user_address2" name="address" type="radio" value="address2"><strong>Sally Smith</strong> 123 Smith St, Boyton Beach, FL 08801, United States <a href="#">Edit</a>
                        </label>
                    </span>
    
                    <p class="help-block"><a href="#"> Add new address</a></p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var $buttons = $('.form-group.radio_buttons'),
    $wrappers = $buttons.find('.radio'),
    $inputs = $buttons.find('input[name="address"]');

$inputs.on('change', function() {
  var $input = $(this),
      $wrapper = $input.closest('.radio'),
      isChecked = $input.is(':checked');

  $wrappers.removeClass('ui-message ui-state-highlight');

  if (isChecked) {
    $wrapper.addClass('ui-message ui-state-highlight');
  } else {
    $wrapper.removeClass('ui-message ui-state-highlight');
  }
});
```

```css
.ui-message.ui-state-highlight {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group radio_buttons optional address-b">
  <label class="radio_buttons optional control-label">Your addresses</label>
  <span class="radio">
                    <label for="user_address1 ">
                        <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="user_address1" name="address" type="radio" value="addres1"><strong>Sally Smith</strong> 3  Plaza, Luiville, Az 932973, United States <a href="#">Edit</a>
                    </label>
                </span>
  <span class="radio">
                    <label for="user_address2">
                        <input class="radio_buttons optional" id="user_address2" name="address" type="radio" value="address2"><strong>Sally Smith</strong> 123 Smith St, Boyton Beach, FL 08801, United States <a href="#">Edit</a>
                    </label>
                </span>

  <p class="help-block"><a href="#"> Add new address</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you . Is it possible to add the  class to the  <span class="radio ui-message ui-state-highlight">

Comment: Updated. Try it now!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work. If I'm answering your question correctly, you want to add the classes to your radio button.

```
$('input[name="address"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).addClass('ui-message ui-state-highlight')
  } else {
     $(this).removeClass('ui-message ui-state-highlight')
  }
});
```

Comment: @user244394 I think the issue was because address wasn't encapsulated in quotes. just added them

Comment: The problem is that the `change` event doesn't fire on buttons you don't click on, so the classes are added but never removed. Updated my answer with a solution.

Comment: @Sean Kwon - it has to add and romve from the  <span class="radio ui-message ui-state-highlight">  block to highlight  It currently add to the input block whihc wont highlight

Answer (score 0):

Sean has a good solution for adding classes via JS. But you can use the `:checked` pseudo selector in CSS to target a checked input element or label associated with an input.

```css
label input:checked {
  opacity: .25;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio"> text
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio"> text
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio"> text
</label>

<br><br>

<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2-1"> <label for="radio2-1">text</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2-2"> <label for="radio2-2">text</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2-3"> <label for="radio2-3">text</label>
```

If you want to use JS/jQuery, setup a `change` event listener, then loop through the inputs and update the classes.

```js
var $inputs = $('input[name="address"]');

$inputs.on('change',function() {
  $inputs.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).addClass('ui-message ui-state-highlight')
    } else {
     $(this).removeClass('ui-message ui-state-highlight')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.ui-message.ui-state-highlight {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="address" type="radio"> <input name="address" type="radio"> <input name="address" type="radio" value="foo">
```

Comment: I second this answer. It's better than a jquery version

Comment: @SeanKwon agreed but CSS can be kinda limited where you can do whatever you want with JS, so not sure if CSS only solution would work for OP.